# ASPxGridView sorting without Headers

Tags: asp.net, sorting, header, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am using devexpress gridview i want sorting in devexpress there is no header in gridview 
Settings-`ShowColumnHeaders="false"` based upon the dropdown selected i need sorting.
i want sorting in C#.

```
switch (ddlSortField.SelectedItem.Value.Trim()) {
case "ViolationDate":
    ASPxGVTickets.SortBy(ASPxGVTickets.Columns["ViolationDate"], DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending);
    break;
case "FName":
    ASPxGVTickets.SortBy(ASPxGVTickets.Columns["FName"], DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending);
    break;
case "LName":
    ASPxGVTickets.SortBy(ASPxGVTickets.Columns["LName"], DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending);
    break;
case "CourtName":
    ASPxGVTickets.SortBy(ASPxGVTickets.Columns["CourtName"], DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending);
    break;
}
```

Comment: would you clarify whether or not your current implementation works? this code looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the **column.FieldName** matches the **SelectedItem.Text**.

If so, modify your code as follows:

```
ASPxGVTickets.SortBy(ASPxGVTickets.Columns[ddlSortField.SelectedItem.Value.Trim()], DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending);
```